# Open Modal After selecting Image File from Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, croppie

I'm using `angular-croppie` to crop my images. the cropper is working fine but there is a problem. I want to open the cropper in The Modal. But when I click on the `choose file button` the modal open with the file explorer window, I want to open the modal after selecting an image from the file explorer and then show that image in the cropper. I'm using AngularJs and Jquery for this function.

CodePen link for my code is [here](https://codepen.io/Zaraa/pen/RQWKbw)

I've tried my best to explain this issue but if you still don't understand then click on the given link.
Please don't mark this question as a duplicate because I've already searched on StackOverflow but still couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added an angular `$watch` to the file (length) which triggered the popup instead of the file open button and it works fine.

Here is your updated codepen

[codepen](https://codepen.io/declanmcd/pen/OQMRzv?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks @DeclanMcD, This solution solved my problem, but now I'm facing another issue, Can you please tell me how to hide base64 Data URL from HTML page?

Comment: You should raise the next issue as another question and give full details

Comment: I've asked another question on S/O and it gets the downvotes, I don't know why.
Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660712/remove-or-hide-base64-url-from-view
It would be very kind of you if you'll help me.